# How to blur a input area when virtual keyboard is hidden using back button?

Tags: javascript, android, tablet

I have a text input area inside an iframe. When input area is focused virtual keyboard pops up and move the iframe container up. But if tablet is in landscape mode then input area cannot be visible because of moving too up. So I tried to solve it by changing the top property of the iframe when input area is focused and tablet is in landscape mode, and change top property back to normal when input area is blurred as virtual keyboard hides. It works fine unless virtual keyboard is hidden using the device's back button. When back button of the device is used to hide the keyboard, input area doesn't lose focus. How can I blur the input area when virtual keyboard is closed using device back button? This works for ipad, problem causes only in android tablet.

Comment: Have you tried to watch the device's height change? you can achieve that by using an Observer design pattern.. that's the first thing that came in mind, I'll try to check other solutions

Comment: I solved the problem using device height change...could not find any other solution...thanks @animake for the help